# JTextArea default value?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, event-dispatch-thread, concurrency

I have been taught only to manage the GUI through the event dispatcher thread. Currently I am using a `textArea.append("something");` outside of the event dispatcher thread, but I want this to always happen at the start of running the program. How can I set a listener to act upon the start up for the program or is what I have done acceptable?

Comment: I suggest you put that line in a method, then call the method from the GUI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the constructor [`JTextArea(String text)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#JTextArea%28java.lang.String%29) on creating it.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create a method in the Class containing the JTextArea called localInitialization() or something like it, which is called in the class's constructor directly after initComponents(). This allows you to put your own custom start-up conditions especially if you are using a GUI Builder such as the one in NetBeans where you cannot edit initComponents().